# Создать циклом переменные со значением из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список и надо чтобы цикл создал переменные со значениями из списка. Т.е чтобы если есть список

```
a['b', 'c', 'd']
```

то цикл должен создать переменные:

```
x1 = b
x2 = c
x3 = d
```

Comment: Зачем?.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну допустим так, но лучше так не делать, используйте лучше словари для таких целей.

```
a = ['b', 'c', 'd']

for i, v in enumerate(a, 1):
    globals()[f'x{i}'] = v

print(x1, x2, x3)
```

Вывод:

```
b c d
```

Answer (score 0):

Если цикл не принципиально то есть деструктуризация:

```
x1 , x2 , x3 = ['b', 'c', 'd']
```